# Converting System.currentTimeMillis() into the current, readable time

Tags: java, android, time, system

Hey - is there a way to use the System.currentTimeMillis(); to have convery that number into a basic output HH:MM in droid?

I am using the sample code:

```
    Toast.makeText(this,
            String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

That outputs the current time in MS since the epoch.  There has got to be a better way to do this rather than convert that large number and display the current time right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat timingFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
timingFormat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Note that this is more of a Java question instead of an Android one, even that the SimpleDateFormat is an Android class, it could also be achieved with a standard Java clas - you should have first googled it before asking a question, and you have to add java to the tags now